# Format DER-encoded private key into PEM in node.js

Tags: node.js, cryptography, private-key, pem, key-generator

How can I format a DER private key which was generated with the node.js crypto library

```
var alice = crypto.createECDH('brainpoolP512t1') 
var keyPair = alice.generateKeys();
var privKey = alice.getPrivateKey();
```

into PEM format?

Comment: PEM is nothing more than a printable representation of DER. The header name is the only thing that you need to think about, but I think `BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY` is the correct one.

Comment: Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655375/format-der-encoded-private-key-into-pem-in-node-js/39669885#39669885) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to update them if they need any improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is `ExportCertPemFile` method in Cert Node.js Reference Documentation by Chilkat Software, see:

- https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/nodejsCertRef.html:

It's available on `npm` on:

- https://www.npmjs.com/~chilkat (choose the correct architecture)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a great [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ec-pem) to get PEM from generated private and public keys using cryptoECDH.